# When i am navigating to a single page in JMter ,the view result tree shows three seggregations for single page . Please assist

Tags: jmeter

1.I have login into the application and i am navigating three different pages , but the view result tree shows two/three seggregation in a single page redirecting to different URLS and hence failing the HTTP request sampler for Timesheet , attendance
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We don't know, bro, JMeter automatically treats [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as not successful therefore I can think of following reasons:

1. Your `Login` request fails causing cascade failure of all Samplers which are below it. I don't see any evidences of [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations/) applied so probably this is the reason.

   Instead of looking at (and showing us) requests take a look at the response, it might be the case you're hammering the login page
2. JMeter's behaviour differs from the real browser's behaviour when it comes to [redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) handling. Try playing with `Redirect automatically` and `Follow redirects` checkboxes in order to configure JMeter to send the same requests as the real browser does

   [image]